# User Groups Best Practices in Ubuntu Server

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, sudo, users

I reciently decided to manage my own web server (Ubuntu/Nginx) and as best practices I went and disabled the root user and created a new one with root privileges. When I created the new user I didn't specify what group to add it to, this is how I created it.

```
adduser newUserName
```

Then I added to the sudo group

```
gpasswd -a newUserName sudo
```

What confuses me is that when I type `cat /etc/group` to see all groups there is a group with the name of the user I created.

```
root
...
newUserName
```

So I started wondering if the way I created the new user is the right way to do it or it's better to create a group first and then add any user with the same privileges to the same group.

- Can someone suggest a best practice to manage users/groups in Ubuntu Server or direct me to where I can find more information?
- What would happen if I create a new group with the same privileges as the existing user and move the existing user newUserName to this folder?

I guess I'm looking to have a better understanding of how users are typically managed in Ubuntu Server.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useradd / usermod command have an option to specify the primary group( -g). If you create a user without -g option a primarygroup will be created with the same name as the new username and the new user will be added to this group.
When user creates a file/directory it gets the group of user's primary group. You can have only one primary group assigned to a user. But you can have multiple secondary groups per user. Use option -G with useradd / usermod command to add secondary groups.

So if you want to create a user and with primary group as sudo , use command:

```
useradd -g sudo <newusername>
```

useradd syntax:

```
useradd -g <primary group> -G <secondarygroup1>,<secondarygroup2> <NewUsername>
```

In linux the primary group will stored to `/etc/passwd` file. `/etc/groups` file will have only list of secondary groups of a user, so `getent group sudo` ( which looks in /etc/group for group info) won't show the primary group of that user ie. sudo . Use `id <username>` or `groups <Username>` to list all the groups, the user is member of. You can also check the 4th field of the `/etc/passwd` for the primary group gid of a user.

Google and Man pages are your best friend when in doubt.

Comment: I just tried adding a couple of  new users using `useradd -g sudo <newusername>` and they show when I show all users `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` but why aren't they listed as members of the `sudo` folder when I type `getent group sudo`? They are not listed as folders either. Can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by sudo folder? You mean sudo group?

Comment: I hope the new info added to the answer will help you.